# Scrollbar indenting the body of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following issue occur in the main content section when there is a scroll bar on the page:

[image]

In other words, when there are more entries that fit within the height of the browser, there is a scroll bar. And when there is a scroll bar, the "Type" and "Added By" get positioned about 10px to the left of where they should be.

Is there a css way to prevent this? Or do I need to use javascript to detect when the scroll bar appears and un-indent the text accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an unavoidable occurrence. There's no way to dictate the browser how their scrollbars will behave with the exception of webkit scrollbar.

I would assume you are directly overflowing from the parent of the table. I implement my HTML by wrapping the parent and overflowing that wrapper instead. Now this doesn't directly fix your issue, but it gives you more freedom to modify the position, padding and width of your direct table container.

```
<div class="table-parent-wrapper" style="overflow:auto">
   <div class="table-parent" style="height: auto;">
       <table></table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Something like this perhaps

[image]